# Why is view state hidden input only present in production even though the code is the same as QA?

Tags: asp.net

We have the same code running in production and QA. I've noticed that in production a view state hidden input is present in a certain spot in the rendered HTML, but it is not present in the same spot in QA. This is causing a problem because the input is breaking a certain JavaScript DOM traversal routine. The input looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="B6523FD1" />
```

So I am wondering:

**Even though the C# ASP.NET code is the same, why would the HTML in production have the hidden input but the HTML in QA does not?**

This is code I have inherited. QA is using IIS version 6 and production is using IIS version 7.5. (I'm not an ASP.Net expert so I am not sure if that is relevant information.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different patch levels (or ASP.NET) on the servers; KB2905247 changes ASP.NET <= 4.5.1 to add the `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` field; ASP.NET 4.5.2 has it built-in.

Comment: Thank you. What do you think is the best thing to do here to remedy this problem?

Comment: @user3666516 - upgrade or patch the QA server. Though you should probably also rewrite your JavaScript, as that's a pretty odd dependency.

Comment: I checked our production machine. It does not have KB2905247 applied to it. Based on your answer I think I was under the impression that the produciton server would have KB2905247, since it sounds like that patch is the source of the __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR field. Am I misunderstanding anything here, or is there something else that could be the source of the __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR field? THANKS!

Comment: @user3666516 - it could also be .NET 4.5.2 and QA have an older version

Comment: I'm sorry I think I don't fully understand your last comment. Production, where this issue is occurring, has .NET version 2.0.50727. As you stated previously (and as [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/09/09/farewell-enableviewstatemac.aspx) seems to indicate) the __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR field is a result of  KB2905247. But I have verified that our production machine does not have KB2905247 applied to it. So I don't understand why the __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR field is showing up in the HTML. Any ideas? Cheers.